# How to return the maximum decimal "precision" and "scale" from pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to create a function the reads dataframe float 64 columns and returns the maximum precision and scale as if it were a SQL data type. For example, let's say I have a column, "Earnings" with values of:

```
Earnings
100.01
100.011423
100.02
100.02231492
100.0313
100.044
```

In this example, the maximum precision would be 11, as the value with the most amount of numbers, 100.02231492, contains 11 total numbers. The maximum scale would also be 8, as that same number has the highest number of decimal places (8). The function would ideally be able to be applied to a list of float64 columns and return the maximum precision and scale for each column.

I have tried something akin to:

```
floats=staking_df.select_dtypes(include=[float])
floats=floats.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('.'))
```

Which would return me

```
Earnings
[100],[01]
[100],[011423]
[100],[02]
[100],[02231492]
[100],[0313]
[100],[044]
```

Ultimately, the function for this column would return a tuple of (11, 8). I am unsure of how to proceed In respect to application to multiple columns. I can't help but think this operation as written thus far is inefficient as well. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: Are these numbers stored as float64? If so, the precision is always 53 bits, as defined in the IEEE 754 standard. Floats are binary, not decimal. The number of decimal digits is only determined when the data is formatted for display. In this case when you call `floats.astype(str)`

Comment: What is the most important feature: the length of number or the number of decimal?

Comment: @Håken Lid Yes they are. My purpose for asking this question, though, is in the context of a procedure where I export float 64 data from pandas into a SQL table as "float" data, then cross reference back to the pandas data. Except the imported SQL float data appears to be rounded when cross referenced to the pandas float 64 data. So I'm trying to devise a solution to import the data as decimal type, but need to infer the maximum precision and scale from the original data. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Corralien both, really, but more importantly the decimal length.

Comment: The decimal length is artificial. Try adding the floats `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1`. The result will be `0.30000000000000004`. This is a rounding error from converting between finite precision decimal and binary. It's not really "wrong", but it sure looks wrong, and it demonstrates that the number of decimal digits is not a reliable measure of precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
get_tuple = lambda x: (len(x)-1, len(x.split('.')[1]))
out = max(df['Earnings'].astype(str).apply(get_tuple), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(out)

# Output:
(11, 8)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I attempted to replicate it earlier but kept running into errors from the syntax ordering. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @corralien, sorry to bother, I have a hard time with lambda expressions. How would I use get_tuple on an entire dataframe?

Comment: Don't worry. Try: `df.astype(str).applymap(get_tuple).max().max()`